# WP Posts Not Adding Up

Tags: database, trash

My WP is hosted at Yahoo I am running WP 3.5.2 and the Posts Page does not add up
    All (4,356) | Published (629) | Sticky (1) | Drafts (265) | Private (88)
WP seems to have an extra 3373 posts. I don't have a Trash option above, so I am guessing these are in the trash.

I have not been able to get a good backup to update. I would like to get rid of the mysterious additional 3373 posts so I can get a BU to upgrade. I pinged Yahoo and they are useless, other seraches on the innertubes point to database tables that need to be pruned but I'm being a wimp on editing the databases. Are there any other options?

Thanks
rb-

Answer (score 0):

Definitely time for an upgrade. :)

Try logging into your admin and following the link below. Just make sure to change 'yoururl.com' to whatever your website name is. If you have posts in the trash, that should take you to your trash to see them.

http://yoururl.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=trash&post_type=post

Comment: Thanks When I go to the URL it says "No posts found in Trash."